# How can I do this command on linux some (sort -u command)

Tags: text-processing

I have two files with contents of some words.

Example

file1 it has 10 words:

```
world
earth
eye
ear
near 
from 
going
want
we 
our
```

Second file2 has 7 words:

```
world
earth
eye
ear
near 
going
want
```

I want output as third file for the words which does not exist in file2.

for example (from , our , we) does not exist in file2.

Comment: Can you give example of desired output?

Answer (score 3):

Just do

```
grep -vFxf file2 file1 > file3
```

This will return those lines that doesn't exist in file2 but in file1 and write  the result to file3.

- `-v`, reverse match, here means those lines if exist only in file2. Without `-v` it will return those lines which are exist in both files.
- `-F`, this is telling `grep` to match the pattern as a fixed pattern string instead of regex (regular expressions)
- `-x`, matches the whole line as pattern string
- `-f`, reading the patterns from a file

Or per your question's title and the command you referred to that `sort -u`, seems you want those unique words (actually lines) either exist in the file1 or file2. then you just need.

```
uniq -u <(sort file1 file2) > file3
```

Comment: If you wanted the lines that are unique in file1 and file2, that would be `sort file1 file2 | uniq -u`. Note that using `-w` here only does what you want/say if there's only one word per line (and no non-word character), so you might as well use `-x` instead of `-w`.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```
comm -23 <(sort file1) <(sort file2) > file3
```

The -23 will suppress the rows contained in either only file2 or in both files.